# How to return to start of the loop if input is wrong?

Tags: python, loops

I have a code (it's a part from bigger code so it may seem a bit stupid).

```
width = int(input('Enter the width: '))
height = int(input('Enter the height: '))

while True:
    point = input('Shall we add a point (Y/N)? ')
    if point == 'Y' or point == 'y':
        x_coord = int(input('Enter X-coordinate: '))
        if x_coord <= 0 or x_coord > width:
            print('The point is outside the system.')
            break
        y_coord = int(input('Enter Y-coordinate: '))
        if y_coord <= 0 or y_coord > width:
            print('The point is outside the system.')
            break
    else:
        if point == 'n' or point == 'N':
            break
        print("Erroneous input!")
```

So my problem is to return to the start of the loop if x- or y-coordinate is wrong. My code just breaks the loop and ends program. So it should give for example.

```
Enter the width: 5
Enter the height: 5
Shall we add a point (Y/N)? Y
Enter X-coordinate: 16
The point is outside the coordinate system.
Shall we add a point (Y/N)? N
```

And the loop should continue so long as you type decide to stop.

However my code gives:

```
Enter the width: 5
Enter the height: 5
Shall we add a point (Y/N)? y
Enter X-coordinate: 16
The point is outside the system.
```

and then ends.

Comment: Use `continue`?

Comment: just `break` in an `else` condition for the last `if`. Remove `break` in `if` when it's not compliant.

Comment: It breaks because you have `break` in your code. You might want to read up on the docs for [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break). You should use `continue` instead

Comment: Use `continue` to go back to the top of the loop, and `break` when you want to end the loop.